¿Cómo pivotear datos de mas de dos columnas en SQL?
Estoy intentando hacer pívot de una tabla donde quiero que me muestre en columnas los  de lo que requisitos de una lista de chequeo con su respectiva fecha. Aquí les muestro un ejemplo de lo que busco:
A continuación esta es la tabla de donde vienen mis datos:

Y esta otra sería la forma en como quiero se me muestre:

No he tenido forma de como hacer esto, hasta el momento el logrado mostrar en columnas los requisitos, pero no e logrado el temas de las fechas.
Aquí te muestro mi consulta real en SQL, en donde las columnas de los requisitos se generan dinámicamente ya que son mas de 30 requisitos y no es optimo estar modificando la consulta para ir agregando requisitos nuevos:
DECLARE @FILTRO VARCHAR(100) = NULL
DECLARE @columnasDinamicas NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @columnasFechasDinamicas NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @columnasDinamicas = STUFF((
SELECT ', [' + REPLACE([CAMPO FECHA] + ' ' +ABREVIATURA , '''', 
'''''')  + ']'  + ', [' + REPLACE(NOMBRE_REQUERIMIENTO, '''', 
'''''')  + ']' 
--SELECT ', [' + REPLACE(NOMBRE_REQUERIMIENTO, '''', '''''')  + ']' 
FROM VW_CHCKLIST_REQUISITOS
WHERE ESTADO = 1
ORDER BY ORDENAMIENTO
FOR XML PATH('')
 ), 1, 2,'')
 --SELECT @columnasDinamicas

 -- Construir la consulta dinámica
DECLARE @consultaDinamica NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @consultaDinamicaDetallada NVARCHAR(MAX) 

SET @consultaDinamica = N'
SELECT [ID EMPLEADO], [TIPO ID],[NUMERO DOCUMENTO], [NOMBRE 
EMPLEADO],[TIPO CONTRATO], [TELEFONO], [ID CARGO], CARGO, [ID 
AREA], AREA,' + @columnasDinamicas + ' 
FROM (SELECT CAU.[ID EMPLEADO], CAU.[TIPO ID], CAU.[NUMERO 
DOCUMENTO], CAU.[NOMBRE EMPLEADO],CAU.[TIPO CONTRATO],CAU. 
[TELEFONO], CAU.[ID CARGO], CAU.CARGO, CAU.[ID AREA], CAU.AREA, 
CAU.[NOMBRE REQUISITO], CAU.CUMPLIMIENTO

FROM VW_CHECKLIST_AUDITADO AS CAU
WHERE CAU.[ESTADO EMPLEADO]=''ACTIVO'' 
AND ((@FILTRO IS NULL OR CAU.[NUMERO DOCUMENTO] = @FILTRO) OR 
(@FILTRO IS NULL OR CAU.[NOMBRE EMPLEADO] LIKE ''%'' + @FILTRO + 
''%''))
) AS DATOS

PIVOT (MAX(CUMPLIMIENTO) FOR [NOMBRE REQUISITO] IN (' + 
@columnasDinamicas + '))  AS pivote'
-- Ejecutar la consulta dinámica
EXEC sp_executesql @consultaDinamica, N'@FILTRO VARCHAR(100)', 
@FILTRO


¿Pueden haber varias filas de un mismo requisito para un mismo empleado, con diferentes fechas y diferentes estados? Si las hay, ¿cuál es el criterio de agregación para el resultado?

Si @jachguate,  pueden haber varios requisitos para un mismo empleado con su respectiva fecha de expedición del requisito. El resultado de agregación para el caso de los requisitos seria el campo  CAU.CUMPLIMIENTO de mi consulta y en el caso de las fechas serian de un campo llamado  CAU.[FECHA VENCIMIENTO] de la vista VW_CHECKLIST_AUDITADO

por favor, lee otra vez mi pregunta, estás respondiendo a algo que yo no pregunté, pero no estás respondiendo a lo que SI pregunté. Un saludo.

Es que la tabla solo almacena un requisito por empleado y la fecha solo corresponde a la fecha de expedición del requisito o curso solicitado, en ningún caso se repite el mimo requisito para un mismo empleado.

He modificado mi consulta SQL, ya e podido agregar los campos de fecha por cada requisito, ahora la cuestión es, como agregar las fechas correspondiente a cada uno.
Se modificó SELECT ', [' + REPLACE(NOMBRE_REQUERIMIENTO, '''', '''''')  + ']'  por SELECT ', [' + REPLACE([CAMPO FECHA] + ' ' +ABREVIATURA , '''', '''''')  + ']'  + ', [' + REPLACE(NOMBRE_REQUERIMIENTO, '''', '''''')  + ']' 

Anoto que se mencionó en comentarios que cada requisito puede aparecer solamente en una fila para cada nombre, por lo que no hace falta, en realidad, utilizar la maquinaria de pivot de SQL Server, sino se puede escribir una consulta que arme la información en columnas que podamos presentar, por ejemplo usando la cláusula case, de la siguiente manera:
case when Requisitos = 'REQUISITO 1' then Estado end

Esta construcción devolverá el estado si la fila corresponde al REQUISITO 1 y null en todos los otros casos. De la misma manera podemos recuperar la fecha.
Finalmente, para obtener una fila por cada nombre, agrupamos por este campo y podemos usar cualquier función de agregación que soporte fechas o cadenas, por ejemplo, min() o max() para quedarnos con la única fila que va a tener datos para cada columna de cada nombre.
Poniendo los datos de entrada en un CTA, con esta consulta:
with
Tabla as (
select * 
  from (values 
          ('JOSE', CAST('20240501' as date), 'REQUISITO 1', 'OK')
        , ('JUAN', '20240413', 'REQUISITO 2', 'OK')
        , ('MARIA', '20240317', 'REQUISITO 3', 'OK')
        , ('ILDA', '20240611', 'REQUISITO 4', 'OK')
        , ('JOSE', '20240412', 'REQUISITO 3', 'OK')
        , ('ILDA', '20240401', 'REQUISITO 1', 'OK')
        , ('ILDA', '20240813', 'REQUISITO 2', 'OK')
       ) q1 (Nombres, Fechas, Requisitos, Estado)
)
select   Nombres 
       , min(case when Requisitos = 'REQUISITO 1' then Estado end) REQUISITO1
       , min(case when Requisitos = 'REQUISITO 1' then Fechas end) FECHA1
       , min(case when Requisitos = 'REQUISITO 2' then Estado end) REQUISITO2
       , min(case when Requisitos = 'REQUISITO 2' then Fechas end) FECHA2
       , min(case when Requisitos = 'REQUISITO 3' then Estado end) REQUISITO3
       , min(case when Requisitos = 'REQUISITO 3' then Fechas end) FECHA3
       , min(case when Requisitos = 'REQUISITO 4' then Estado end) REQUISITO4
       , min(case when Requisitos = 'REQUISITO 4' then Fechas end) FECHA4
  from Tabla
 group by Nombres
 order by Nombres;

Obtengo este resutado:
Nombres REQUISITO1 FECHA1     REQUISITO2 FECHA2     REQUISITO3 FECHA3     REQUISITO4 FECHA4
------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
ILDA    OK         2024-04-01 OK         2024-08-13 NULL       NULL       OK         2024-06-11
JOSE    OK         2024-05-01 NULL       NULL       OK         2024-04-12 NULL       NULL
JUAN    NULL       NULL       OK         2024-04-13 NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL
MARIA   NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       OK         2024-03-17 NULL       NULL

(4 rows affected)


Edición:
Dado que el AP no se conforma con menos que una consulta dinámica, en el sentido que incorpore las columnas que hagan falta según los datos de Requisitos almacenados en la base de datos, por  si los datos cambian en el futuro, acá la dejo:
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Tabla', 'U') is not null drop table #Tabla;

with
Tabla as (
select * 
  from (values 
          ('JOSE', CAST('20240501' as date), 'REQUISITO 1', 'OK')
        , ('JUAN', '20240413', 'REQUISITO 2', 'OK')
        , ('MARIA', '20240317', 'REQUISITO 3', 'OK')
        , ('ILDA', '20240611', 'REQUISITO 4', 'OK')
        , ('JOSE', '20240412', 'REQUISITO 3', 'OK')
        , ('ILDA', '20240401', 'REQUISITO 1', 'OK')
        , ('ILDA', '20240813', 'REQUISITO 2', 'OK')
        , ('ILDA', '20240813', 'NUEVOREQ', 'OK')
       ) q1 (Nombres, Fechas, Requisitos, Estado)
)
select *
  into #Tabla
  from Tabla
;

declare @columnasDinamicas varchar(max);
declare @consulta varchar(max);

with
X as (
select distinct Requisitos
  from #Tabla
)
select @columnasDinamicas = 
       (select ', min(case when Requisitos = ''' + Requisitos + ''' then Estado end) as [' + Requisitos + ']'
             + ', min(case when Requisitos = ''' + Requisitos + ''' then Fechas end) as [Fecha_' + Requisitos + ']'
          from X
          for XML path('')
       )

set @consulta = 'select Nombres ' + @columnasDinamicas + ' from #Tabla group by Nombres order by Nombres';

exec(@consulta);

Que produce este resultado:
Nombres NUEVOREQ Fecha_NUEVOREQ REQUISITO 1 Fecha_REQUISITO 1 REQUISITO 2 Fecha_REQUISITO 2 REQUISITO 3 Fecha_REQUISITO 3 REQUISITO 4 Fecha_REQUISITO 4
------- -------- -------------- ----------- ----------------- ----------- ----------------- ----------- ----------------- ----------- -----------------
ILDA    OK       2024-08-13     OK          2024-04-01        OK          2024-08-13        NULL        NULL              OK          2024-06-11
JOSE    NULL     NULL           OK          2024-05-01        NULL        NULL              OK          2024-04-12        NULL        NULL
JUAN    NULL     NULL           NULL        NULL              OK          2024-04-13        NULL        NULL              NULL        NULL
MARIA   NULL     NULL           NULL        NULL              NULL        NULL              OK          2024-03-17        NULL        NULL

(4 rows affected)


El ejemplo esta muy bien, pero como lo harías en el caso de que vayan ingresando mas requisitos? Tendrías que estar modificando tu consulta de a cada rato para poder actualizar el reporte. Por esa razón compartí mi consulta SQL en donde consulto la tabla de requisitos para asi poder tener los nombres de cada columna dinámicamente y no tenga que estar modificando mi consulta.

@James: He realizado el ejemplo con los datos que tú mismo has dado. Observé que construyes una consulta dinámica, pero ese ya es tu trabajo. Si comprendes como funciona la construcción de esta consulta, puedes hacer tú la programación para que se genere el query de manera dinámica similar a como ya lo venías haciendo antes. De esa manera a medida que se agreguen más, el query se irá adaptando.

Bueno, los datos que puse en las imágenes, es una manera grafica y sencilla para que se pudiera entender lo que estoy buscando por lo mismo compartí mi consulta dinámica para llevarlo a ese ejemplo. De todas formas muchas gracias.

Listo. Actualicé la respuesta, es de esperar que el AP haga lo que corresponde para adaptar la respuesta a sus necesidades, espero que ya con esto te hagas una mejor idea, pues tampoco es de esperar que yo escriba la consulta específica para tu tarea escolar, y menos para tu trabajo. Un saludo.

Por eso mismo puse un ejemplo porque no pretendo que hagas mi trabajo, no sabes cuanto agradezco tu ayuda. Pero hay que saber como expresarnos.
Gracias

La respuesta (como de costumbre para @jachguate) es muy buena. Pero te recomiendo que evites pivotear datos dinámicos en SQL y trates de hacerlo en la aplicación. Cada caso es distinto y debes evaluar las ventajas y desventajas de las opciones.
